# Select one probability out of two from XGBoost returned predict_proba

Tags: probability, xgboost

I have trained an XGBoost Classifier (the model is called "model" and the Target variable is either 0 or 1 ) on sample called X.
Then I have estimated the probability as follows:

```
valid_pred = model.predict_proba(X)
```

When I print valid_pred I get this :

```
[[0.6834905  0.31650946]]
```

So, that means that:

```
Probability of being 0 is 0.6834905
Probability of being 1 is 0.31650946
```

How can I always get the probability of being 1. So, is there a code that always return the second element in [[0.6834905  0.31650946]] (that would be 0.31650946)?

Comment: with `.ravel()[1]` after `predict_proba` to flatten and take 1st entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
valid_pred = model.predict_proba(X)[:,1]
```

or

```
valid_pred = model.predict_proba(X)
valid_pred = [sub_array[1] for sub_array in valid_pred]
```